# XML bindings generation file does not compile

Tags: java, xml, delphi, binding, xsd

I am working on a project involving a Java back-end with Delphi front-end. I am attempting to generate XML bindings based off of an .xsd in java. The XSD contains a object called TaskList which has item Tasks. Tasks is a list of Task. When I generate the XML bindings Delphi attempts a CreateCollection() function using TXMLTaskList but throws an error because TXMLTaskList is IXMLNode instead of IXMLNodeCollection.

I am still new to using XSD files and the XML bindings generation feature but based off of what little I do understand I was assuming since TaskList contains a single object Tasks that it should not be getting used in the CreateCollection Function, instead I would think that Tasks which is a list of Task should be getting used.

This is the line that my XML bindings file is throwing an error on:

```
FExportOnClientChange := CreateCollection(TXMLTaskList, IXMLTask, 
  'exportOnClientChange') as IXMLTaskList;
```

This is my TXMLTaskLisk, showing that it is an TXMLNode instead of TXMLNodeCollectionClass which CreateCollection is looking for.

```
type
  TXMLTaskList = class(TXMLNode, IXMLTaskList)
  protected
    { IXMLTaskList }
    function Get_Tasks: IXMLTasks;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;
```

In my attemps to figure out the problem I did notice that if I make TaskList an unbounded list of tasks and leave tasks as an unbounded list of task that everything generates fine in the delphi xml file, but that would mean that I have a list of a list which is not what I am wanting.

One thing that might be hard to tell here is that TaskList and tasks are in different XSD files although they are linked.

```
<complexType name="TaskList">
    <sequence>
        <element name="tasks" type="struct:tasks"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>


<complexType name="tasks">
    <sequence>
        <element ref="struct:task" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on your own in the Delphi department.

With that said, I do use xjc and xsd files to generate Java classes.

It looks like you included in your question a sample of the xsd that you know is wrong.  In your xsd sample you have a sequence of sequences - I'd expect your sample to generate a class with a collection of collections of task objects.

If I understand your question correctly what you want is for TaskList to contain a collection of tasks.  That shouldn't be too hard.  What have you tried?

Here is an example of how I generate a Thresholds object that contains a list of individual Threshold objects:

```
<xsd:element name="Thresholds" type="ThresholdsType"/>
<xsd:complexType name ="ThresholdsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="Threshold" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="interpolate" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="parameter" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    <xsd:attribute name="unitSystem" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="Threshold" type="ThresholdType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="ThresholdType">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:attribute type="xsd:string" name="id" use="optional"/> 
            <xsd:attribute type="xsd:double" name="minInclusive" use="optional"/>
            <xsd:attribute type="xsd:double" name="maxExclusive" use="optional"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Here is the start of the generated ThresholdsType java class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ThresholdsType", propOrder = {
    "threshold"
})
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement(name="ThresholdsType implements Cloneable, Named, Visitable, CopyTo, Equals, HashCode, ToString")
public class ThresholdsType implements Cloneable, Named, Visitable, CopyTo, Equals, HashCode, ToString
{

    @XmlElement(name = "Threshold")
    protected List<ThresholdType> threshold;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "interpolate")
    protected String interpolate;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "parameter")
    protected String parameter;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "unitSystem")
    protected String unitSystem;
    @XmlTransient
    private QName jaxbElementName;
    ...
```

I should have renamed the "threshold" field inside ThresholdsType to "thresholds" but other than that it works great.

Does this not work?

```
<complexType name="TaskList">
   <sequence>
     <element ref="struct:task" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
   </sequence>
</complexType>
```